# traversal method with a return value

Tags: tree, inorder

for trees, in traversal methods I want the values to be returned. the  method i tried only returns one value.

```
 int inorder(BSTNode r) {
   int result = 0 ;
    if (r != null) {
        inorder(r.getLeft());
     result= r.getData();
        inorder(r.getRight());  
    }
   return result;
}
```

this code works perfectly but I want the method to return the values instead

```
private void inorder(BSTNode r) {
    if (r != null) {
        inorder(r.getLeft());
        System.out.print(r.getData() + " ");
        inorder(r.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "values"?

Comment: node "data" in my tree

Comment: You currently do. Tree's root, to be exact, since you're not using neither the left child's, nor the right one's data. What is your expected output, exactly? What does the `r.getData()` return?

Comment: all nodes of the tree in that order: 1.  Go the left subtree, and perform an inorder traversal 
on that node.

2.  Print out the value of the current node.

3.  Go to the right child node, and then perform 
an inorder traversal on that right child node's subtree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use some kind of list structure to accumulate the data:

```
void inorder(BSTNode r, List list) {
  if (r != null) {
    inorder(r.getLeft(), list);
    list.add(r.getData());
    inorder(r.getRight(), list);
  }
}
```

Invoking the function with

```
List list = new List();
inorder(bst, list);
```

After inorder completes, `list` will contain the the values of the tree.

The exact syntax would depend on the language you're using.

Comment: java, when invoking the method what should i send to list, is that correct inorder(root, null)

Comment: for java you would create a list `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>()` and then call `inorder(bst, list)`, where T is the type of the data stored in the tree